# Import mail from another Gmail account, but deduplicate?

Tags: gmail

If you have two Gmail accounts, one of which is forwarding to the other and you want to import ALL of the mail from the other one minus the messages that were already forwarded to the second account, is that possible?

Is there some sort of unique ID attached to each email so that they'll dedupe?

Comment: Setup both accounts in Outlook using IMAP.  Copy all emails from one account to the other.  At this point I have personally used a plugin to located duplicate emails and ( my personal taste ) label the duplicate with a specific label.